# Why doesn't clear: right clear the right side of a paragraph element in a two columns text?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to understand float and I made a two columns of text:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  float: left;
  background: pink;
}

#p1 {
  width: 50%;
  clear: right;
}

#p2 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">Paragraph 1.</p>
<p id="p2">Paragraph 2.</p>
```

Since I set #p1 to clear:right, I thought #p2 text would go below it, since in my understanding, clear:right says no other element should float at the right side of #p1.

The same happens if I set #p2 to float:right. They document looks the same, nothing happens.

I'm strugling to understand why doesn't #p2 text get out of #p1 side. Could someone explain me, please?

Comment: I respect your desire to learn, but just don't use floats. They're mostly obsolete and have caused many developers many headaches. Use `inline-block`, flexbox, or grid.

Comment: FWIW, the days of using `float` as a means of building layouts are mostly in the past.  In 2021, I would recommend only using [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) for its intended purpose of allowing content to float around a container such as an image, and use [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), [`grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids), and maybe [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) for layout purposes.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: @isherwood Thanks! I'm taking a coursera course on web dev for beginners, but I guess it's outdated then

Comment: Sounds like it. A lot has changed in CSS in the last few years, particularly with the demise of Internet Explorer. Check those expiration dates!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing refers to getting below what has come before, not what comes after. Also, if each element has 50% of the width, there's really nothing to clear from the same side. You'd have to clear the opposite side or *both* sides.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: pink;
}

#p1 {
  clear: right;
}

#p2 {
  float: right;
  clear: left;
}

#p3 {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">Paragraph 1.</p>
<p id="p2">Paragraph 2 (cleared left).</p>
<p id="p3">Paragraph 3 (cleared both ways).</p>
```